# Accommodate Emacs' lock files for React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, emacs

Currently, I have to disable Emacs' lock files, `(create-lockfiles nil)` to conveniently develop my React Native project. Otherwise, if I make file changes and do not immediately save them, the file change is detected while running `npx react-native start`, then the Metro Bundler stops with an error: `Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'C:\<project-location>\.#<filename>.js'`.

Is there a way to skip these files so the Metro Bundler doesn't panic with every lock file creation of Emacs?